# Yii FullcalendarGraphWidget how to provide $model->search(); result to the FullCalendar?

Tags: yii, fullcalendar, yii-extensions

Instead of CGridView I'm using fullCalendar extension to display my data in the calendar as an event. Along with that I've filter option.

In CGridView we can write `'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),` to get the search data. Similarly how can I provide the same data to the fullCandar extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it by fetching the data in the Controller as following and transforming it to an array in the shape which the fullcalendar expects:

```
public function actionCalendar() 
{
    $data=CalendarEntry::model()->findAll();

    $model = array();
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        array_push($model, array(
            'id' => $item->id,
            'title' => $item->datetext,
            'start' => $item->datedate,
            'url' => CController::createUrl('calendar/view', array ('id' => $item->id)),
        ));
    };
    $this->render('calendar',array('model'=>$model));
}
```

And in my calendar view I'm then just setting the model:

```
$this->widget('application.extensions.fullcalendar.FullcalendarGraphWidget',
    array(
        'data'=> $model,        

        'htmlOptions'=>array(
               'style'=>'width:800px;margin: 0 auto;'
        ),
    )
);
```